# Auto selection Woocommerce variable

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce

I've a product with 4 variables
[List of variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgYRN.jpg)

Each one has this items: 1 Year, 3 Years, 5 Years and None

I know that i can set a default option but what i need is that when i select one of this options in any variation the others get autoselected with none, why? because i have like this my variations

[My variables are like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va1mY.jpg)

Any help would be very nice, thnx

Comment: Hi, please clarify your question and describe what you have tried etc. You can't help you unless you specify the problem.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to be more especific, there are 4 different variables, but the user only have to choose one:
Option1: 24x7 FortiCare y FortiGuard Enterprise Protection (1y, 3y, 5y or none)
Option2: 8x5 FortiCare y FortiGuard UTM Protection (1y, 3y, 5y or none)
Option3: 24x7 FortiCare y FortiGuard UTM Protection (1y, 3y, 5y or none)
Option4: ASE FortiCare y FortiGuard 360 Protection (1y, 3y, 5y or none)

If i choose any of the options in 1y, 3y or 5y the other 3 options need to be as none.

Comment: I've tyed to hide the "choose one option" item but it gave me a blank space and I need to select the none option, i'll let you the link of an example so you can check it 

https://datacenter360.net/catalogo/cisco/test-2/